# Creating a single sine wave within specified range

Tags: java, linked-list, javasound

I am trying to imitate a string instrument. I have a ring buffer implemented as a Linked List with all of the values initialized at 0 to represent a sine wave at rest.

I am writing a pluck() method that replaces the N elements(all values currently at 0) in the buffer with N samples of a single sine wave with values between -.5 and +5.

Can you help me with the math aspect of making this happen?

Comment: *"Can you help me with the math aspect of making this happen?"*  You most likely won't find a tutor on SO, since that is not what it is for.  You'll have better luck showing what you have tried and asking a specific question.  Also, don't forget to add a question mark to questions.  As it stands, I am voting to close this as 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a sine function for your fundamental frequency, and others if you want to introduce harmonics (with `sqrt(2)` frequencies ratio), then add an attack slope and duration, idem for sustain and release. This is the basics of old-school electronic music :)

Comment: *"idem for sustain and release"*  DYM 'item'?  What is an 'idem'?

Comment: _idem_ is latin for "the same thing".